# Unable to write a fraction in JupyterLab

Tags: python

I am trying to write a fraction inside the superscript of a variable (in my case $frac{1}{3}$.
I get a long error: [image]

```
plt.ylabel('$\\frac{\delta T}{\delta t}$ $[^oR/min]$')
```

Comment: Without the error, it is going to be hard for people here to help. Could you please edit your post, and include the error you are getting?

Comment: you would need `\\frac` to encode `\frac` in a single quote python string

Comment: @David Carlisle This solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: the error shown is not from the code you show `\delta` ???

Comment: This code worked: plt.ylabel('$\\frac{\delta T}{\delta t}$  $[^oR/min]$')

Comment: yes but that code is unrelated to the code you showed in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a TeX issue or TeX error message but
you would need `\\frac` to encode `\frac` in a single quote python string